# Let g be a monotone-increasing function in [a,b]. Does $\int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx\leq \frac{1}{g(a)}\int_a^b f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have seen this inequality in many proofs but I don't know how it is possible, could someone help me to demonstrate or giving me some hint to make it out?

Comment: Let me give an example. Set f(x)=1, g(x)=x, a=5 b=8: It is true that $ln(8)-ln(5)=\frac{3}{5}$ and g is not monotone-decreasing

Comment: Let $a=0,b=1,f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x\ne 0$ and $g(0)=10$,, then $∫_a^b f/g dx=1$, but $1/g(0) ∫_a^b fdx=\frac1{10}$

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we have that $$\int_a^b g(x)\,dx \leq (b-a)\cdot\displaystyle\sup_{x \in [a,b]}g(x).$$ Since we have your $g(x)$ in the denominator, this becomes
$$\int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\,dx \leq \displaystyle\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\frac{1}{g(x)}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{\displaystyle\inf_{x\in[a,b]}g(x)}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$ Thus, your equation will hold true when $g$ attains its minimum/infimum at $x = a$, which happens for example if $g$ is increasing.

Comment: I get the first inequiality, but the second one no, could you explain me why does we can put out g(x) in that expression?

Comment: It's the same idea as the first inequality. Since integration is monotonic, it means that if function A is larger than function B, than the integral over function A will always be larger than the integral over function B. Well, the supremum of a function is always larger or equal to the function itself, so we can say that the integral over function A (the supremum) is greater than or equal to the integral over function B (the original function). Then, we can pull it out since it is a constant, and we get the inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much